# ACE Editor: disable syntax validation, but keep syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, text, ace-editor

I've tried,
`editor.session.setOption("useWorker", false);`

but this seems to also turn off syntax highlighting - how should I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

you probably have a typo somewhere else, it works in the attached example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script> 
  <style>
    #editor1, #editor2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}
    #editor1 {bottom: 50%}
    #editor2 {top: 50%}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="editor1">var + jshint</div>
 <div id="editor2">var + no jshint</div>
 <script>
   var editor1 = ace.edit("editor1")
   editor1.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
   var editor2 = ace.edit("editor2")
   editor2.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript")
   editor2.session.setOption("useWorker", false);
 </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

in angular, if we use options like below we can prevent highlight syntax errors.
I have tried,
options: any = { maxLines: 1000, printMargin: false,useWorker:false };